# How do I help with this site?

Tags: support

I've been wanting a Literature Stack Exchange for a while.

I'm mainly on [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) with 5,000 rep (would have continued to grow, but a current job as an editor keeps me busy.)  That said, I'd like to help with the site.

How do I help?

Comment: Hey, Michael, how about you join us in chat.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room

Answer (score 13):

<sub>I'm writing this as an FAQ-style answer, addressed to everybody, not just you.</sub>

---

**There are lots of ways to help!**

You can help in *lots* of different ways!

1. **Ask questions**.

   We always need more questions - it's very hard to *answer* questions if there aren't any! We'd like good, interesting, on-topic questions about Literature - scan our [highly voted questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) for examples.
2. **Answer questions**.

   It's not much use having lots of questions without answers, so please come see if you can help answer some questions! Especially our [unanswered questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/unanswered); take a look and see if you can answer any. Scan our [highly voted answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) for some examples.
3. **Edit**.

   If you see something that can be improved in a post, there's always an 'edit' button! If you click that, you can help improve our content.
4. **Vote.**

   This one's very important - **if we don't vote, this site will fail**. You can both upvote and downvote, and you have 40 votes a day - use them!
5. **Participate in Meta.**<sup>1</sup>

   Meta - this site - is very important. It's where all of the important decisions happen, like what our major policies are, what tags we should use, what's on topic, and all those things. Get in on the action!

Hope to see you around!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Hat-tip to @wythagoras for mentioning this.</sub>

Comment: Suggestion: 5. Participate in Meta. Meta participation is also important, especially in a young site such as this one, because it is here where there are discussions about the scopes, about the tags, and other important things.

Comment: @wythagoras Right, I knew I was forgetting *something*. Thanks!